# Problem with java and conditional (game of life)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to implement The Game of Life in java, as an exercise to learn this language.

Unfortunately I have a problem, as I don't seem able to make this program run correctly.

I implemented a torodial sum (the plane is a donut) with no problem:

```
    int SumNeighbours (int i, int j) {

  int value = 0;


  value = world[( i - 1 + row  ) % row][( j - 1 + column  ) % column]+world[( i - 1 + row  ) % row][j]+world[( i - 1 + row  ) % row][( j + 1 ) % column];

  value = value + world[i][( j - 1 + column  ) % column] + world[i][( j + 1 ) % column];

  value = value + world[( i + 1 ) % row][( j - 1 + column  ) % column] + world[( i + 1 ) % row][j]+world[ ( i+1 ) % row ][( j + 1 ) % column];


  return value;
 }
```

And it sums correctly when I test it:

```
 void NextWorldTest () {

  int count;

  int [][] nextWorld = new int[row][row];

  nextWorld = world;


  for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<column; j++) {

    count = SumNeighbours(i,j);

    System.out.print(" " + count + " ");       


   }

   System.out.println();

  }

  world=nextWorld;



 }
```

Unfortunately when I add the conditions of game of life (born/death) the program stop working correctly, as it seems not able anymore to count correctly the alive cells in the neighborhood. It counts where there are none, and it doesn't count when there are some. E.g.: it doesn't count the one below some living cells.

It's a very odd behaviour, and it's been giving me a headache for 3 days now... maybe I'm missing something basic about variables?

Here you can find the class.

```
    void NextWorld () {

  int count;

  int [][] nextWorld = new int[row][column];

  nextWorld = world;


  for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<column; j++) {

    count = SumNeighbours(i,j);

    System.out.print(" " + count + " ");


    if (  ( world[i][j] == 0) &&  ( count == 3 )  ) {

     nextWorld[i][j] = 1;

    } else if ( ( world[i][j] == 1 ) && ( (count == 3) || (count == 2) )) {

     nextWorld[i][j] = 1;

    } else {

     nextWorld[i][j]=0;

    }


   }

   System.out.println();

  }

  world=nextWorld;



 }

}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Below you can find the full package.

```
    package com.GaOL;

public class GameWorld {

 int [][] world;

 int row;

 int column;

 public int GetRow() {

  return row;
 }

 public int GetColumn() {

  return column;
 }

 public int  GetWorld (int i, int j) {


  return world[i][j];

 }

 void RandomGen (int size, double p1) {

  double randomCell;

  row = size;
  column = size;

  world = new int[row][column];

  for (int i = 0; i<row; i++ ) {
   for (int j = 0; j<column; j++ ) {

    randomCell=Math.random();

    if (randomCell < 1-p1) {

     world[i][j] =  0;

    } else {

     world[i][j] =  1;

    }



   }

  }

 }

 void printToConsole() {

  double test = 0; 

  for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<column; j++) {

    if ( world[i][j] == 0 ) {

     System.out.print("   ");

    } else {
     System.out.print(" * ");

     test++;

    }

   }

   System.out.println("");  

  }


  System.out.println("ratio is " + test/(row*column));


}

 int SumNeighbours (int i, int j) {

  int value = 0;


  value = world[( i - 1 + row  ) % row][( j - 1 + column  ) % column]+world[( i - 1 + row  ) % row][j]+world[( i - 1 + row  ) % row][( j + 1 ) % column];

  value = value + world[i][( j - 1 + column  ) % column] + world[i][( j + 1 ) % column];

  value = value + world[( i + 1 ) % row][( j - 1 + column  ) % column] + world[( i + 1 ) % row][j]+world[ ( i+1 ) % row ][( j + 1 ) % column];


  return value;
 }

 void NextWorldTest () {

  int count;

  int [][] nextWorld = new int[row][row];

  nextWorld = world;


  for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<column; j++) {

    count = SumNeighbours(i,j);

    System.out.print(" " + count + " ");       


   }

   System.out.println();

  }

  world=nextWorld;



 }


 void NextWorld () {

  int count;

  int [][] nextWorld = new int[row][column];

  nextWorld = world;


  for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<column; j++) {

    count = SumNeighbours(i,j);

    System.out.print(" " + count + " ");


    if (  ( world[i][j] == 0) &&  ( count == 3 )  ) {

     nextWorld[i][j] = 1;

    } else if ( ( world[i][j] == 1 ) && ( (count == 3) || (count == 2) )) {

     nextWorld[i][j] = 1;

    } else {

     nextWorld[i][j]=0;

    }


   }

   System.out.println();

  }

  world=nextWorld;



 }

}
```

and here the test class:

```
    package com.GaOL;

public class GameTestClass {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

  GameWorld prova = new GameWorld();

  prova.RandomGen(10, 0.02);

  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {

   prova.printToConsole();

   prova.NextWorld();

  }



 }

}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer you if a) you formatted your code; b) you presented a *short* example of what's wrong. There's much more code here than you need demonstrate the problem, I'm sure.

Comment: I reformatted... there was a problem with StackOverflow editor... and conditional operator tag is there because the code break when I add the ifs....

Comment: I think there isn't any troubles with conditional operators. So I removed this tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, problem is in arrays assignments. What are you doing here?

```
int [][] nextWorld = new int[row][row];
nextWorld = world;
```

you should create new array `[row][column]` and then fill it according data from world.

And more

- in Java you can do smt like `anArray.length` and `anArray[0].length`, so you do not need row and  column variables
- you should name all you method starting with low letter, like `sumNeighbours()` instead of  `SumNeighbours()`

**upd**:there was typo in second advise: fixed

Comment: yes that part is wrong, but it isn't the problem as the array is a square.... thanx for help :)

Comment: @Muad'Dib, What do you think is going on line `nextWorld = world;`?

Comment: it's making a copy of world in nextWorld, so that I can modify its value but still having an original reference to make the sums... am I wrong?

Comment: @Muad'Dib, actually, you don't need do any such copy/assignment at all. Just create empty nextWorld, fill it (as you done) and then make assignment (as you done too).

Comment: thank you very much.... you solved it.... why such a small line was breaking so much code? I was copying by value, wasn't I? Was it by reference?

Comment: @Muad'Dib You only create one more reference by such syntax. To copy arrays you can use 'System.arraycopy' (not deep!). In fact you should avoid arrays by using Lists (not in this case). P.S. Don't forget to accept answers.